# How to add a route prefix to specific modules using NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I want to add routing prefixes at the module level and/or have complex global routing prefix logic in general.

I know I can use the undocumented function `NestApplication.setGlobalPrefix` to set a single global prefix:

```
// main.ts
app.setGlobalPrefix(version);
```

However, I want to set prefixes at the module level in this case.

It appears I could achieve this by setting my desired prefix into the decorators at the controller level:

```
//controler.ts
@Get('/PREFIX/health')
async getHealth() {

  // TODO: implement
  return {};
}
```

But this seems fairly hacky and error-prone. Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

##### Update 2021

NestJS now [supports the original answer natively](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module).

In addtion, NestJS v8 [also adds more sophisticated routing](https://trilon.io/blog/announcing-nestjs-8-whats-new#API-versioning) when the primary function is versioning an API:

```js
@Controller({
  path: 'cats',
  version: '1', // 
})
export class CatsController {
...
```

##### Original Answer

The most robust way to accomplish this in NestJS is to use the [nest-router](https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-router) package to create a *routing tree*.

```sh
yarn add nest-router
# or npm i nest-router
```

Create a file next to `main.ts` called `routes.ts` like so:

```
import { Routes } from 'nest-router';
import { YourModule } from './your/your.module';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/v1',
    module: YourModule,
  },
];
```

Then, inside your `app.module.ts` file, add the router **before** any other modules are loaded:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoutes(routes),
    YourModule,
    DebugModule
  ],

})
```

Now when you navigate to `YourModule` controller, all of its routes will be prefixed with e.g. `v1` in this case:

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/v1/your/operation
```

Using this approach gives you the most flexibility as each module does not need to know how it will be prefixed; the application can decide at a higher level. Almost more advanced prefixes can be computed dynamic versus relying on a static string.

Comment: It seems package is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

For me, adding a third party package just to achieve this would be a bit unnecessary, let alone the risk of it being outdated/unmaintained. You can add your custom route prefix in the `Controller` class instead.

```
  @Controller('custom/prefix')
  export const MyController {

     @Get('health')
     getHealth() {
       //this route would be: custom/prefix/health
       return {};
     }

     @Get('other')
     getOther() {
       //this route would be: custom/prefix/other
       return {};
     }
  }
```

Then just simply add this controller inside your `Module`

Answer (score 2):

You can now use either the RouterModule configuration or you can exclude some paths from the global prefix configuration (or mix both):

RouterModule:
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module#router-module

Global prefix "exclude":
https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix